# Safari & Chrome crashes when accessing inbox under IT Security

Tags: support

Safari on OSX crashes each and every time I access my inbox on Security.SE  It has no effect on my Stackoverflow account.

I have the full stack trace if you want it.  Contact me at myname at gmail if you want it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, it has to do with [this vulnerability: Rendering bug crashes OS X, iOS apps with string of Arabic characters](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/08/rendering-bug-crashes-os-x-and-ios-apps-with-string-of-arabic-characters/).

We'd had some spam using this, we've deleted those posts now. The malicious input has also been blacklisted so no new posts that include it will be made.

Comment: Even though the posts are deleted, I'm still unable to access my inbox under Sec.SE.  I can access it over Stackoverflow.

Comment: @makerofthings7 can you try another browser? Firefox, or anything on Windows? Try and get us a screenshot?

Comment: I tried Chrome and Safari both on OSX... will fire up Windows 8 under parallels...

Comment: The error no longer exists anywhere.  I suppose someone did something on the back end...

Comment: yep, cleaned up those offensive posts...

Comment: Wow a real in the wild vulnerability on Sec.se!